# Editing buffers in Arcmap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

Working for an environmental agency, they ask me to edit in ArcGIS the sizes of the buffers for the same layer.

Is that possible to change it using python in the field calculator?

If yes, I seek an example of python code or if there is another way I'll take too.

Comment: Do you have access to the original data layer? Or just the buffer layer?

Comment: I first created a fictional layer  with some points to try on it. and add a column buffer. I do not created need buffer layer yet

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the buffer size using the arcpy's Buffer_analysis:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, buffer_distance_or_field, {line_side}, {line_end_type}, {dissolve_option}, {dissolve_field}, {method})
```

The third parameter of the function determines the buffer distance in the current coordinate system units.

If there are existing buffers for the in_features you will have to remove them first (out_feature_class) and re run with your new buffer distance.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I never used python before so I tried that : arcpy. Buffer_analysis(Field1, Buffer,1000). And got a window appearing saying "There was a failure during processing, check the Geoprocessing Results window for detail". I think the syntax is not valid.

Comment: I would recommend reading the link i posted for more information. The first parameter is not a field, but a feature/layer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I noticed the mistake. I tried on python and it works, the size of the buffer changed for all the data. The thing is I would like to add different sizes for some data. Do you have any idea how to do that?  Cheers

Comment: yea try this. http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/analysis_tools/multiple_ring_buffer_analysis_.htm              also please mark my answer as accepted so i get extra points! haha